# Analyzing Tschaikowsky's Morgengebet

Tags: theory, chords, chord-theory, chord-inversions

[image]

if you see at the 5th measure from the photo,
there is a question mark.

How did that F#7/A# came out all of a sudden ?

Was it possible because at the measure before there is a bass movement moving down from B ? so that makes it a half step movement ?

or is it just possible that Secondary Dominants could come out of nowhere all of a sudden ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, It's possible that secondary dominants can come out of the blue all of a sudden. While the chromatic bassline definitely supports those harmonies, I don't think it's necessary in order for those chords to be used.

In this case, the F#(7)/A# starts off a long chain of secondary dominants, so it sounds even stranger. Such long chains of secondary dominants aren't unheard of, though: see the [ragtime progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ragtime_progression) for more details.

Comment: Ups, I wrote this answer 5 hours ago and was interrupted to send. Now I’m afraid my answer doesn’t give any new information but exactly the same as Dekkadeci’s.

Comment: What do you mean by "  I don't think it's necessary in order for those chords to be used. " ?

Comment: @HyunYooPark - I mean that I don't think a chromatic bassline is necessary in order to kick off a secondary dominant chain like in the example.

Answer (score 0):

> or is it just possible that Secondary Dominants could come out of nowhere all of a sudden ?

Yes, secondary dominants have this properties.

And mind the chord progression: measure 4 - 8, this is an entire cadence of secondary dominants following the circle of fifths. This progression is quite usual in all epoques and styles of music.

Comment: what do you mean by "And mind the chord progression: measure 4 -" ?

Comment: sorry, as I had no internet the second part of my answer has been deleted. I will edit.